# How to use linebreaksbr filter method in Django view?

Tags: django, django-templates

[linebreaksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) is Django's template filter method.

Such as:

```
<td>{% filter linebreaksbr %}{% render_result result %}{% endfilter %}</td>
```

How to use it in view.py?

That means I want to get the same data result from view and download to csv file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To use it in your views, you can do:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import linebreaksbr
```

and in then

```
linebreaksbr(varname)
```

where `varname` is the variable.

Here is the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py)

Comment: Thank you very much! Another question:Why I can write `{% filter linebreaksbr %}{% render_result result %}{% endfilter %}` in template,but can't I write `linebreaksbr(render_result result)` in view.py?It said: **invalid syntax**.

Comment: It expects a variable as a parameter, and `render_result result` is not a valid variable. Hence the syntax error

Comment: Yes,this way is right: `linebreaksbr(render_result(result))` in the view.py.Thanks!